# How to post code in SO

Tags: support, markdown, code-formatting

I got tired to put code in SO. The four indentations I made is not working. For example, I am posting below line with four spaces forth and the back.

```
print("Haihello");
```

Comment: Click that 1010 button on the toolbar.

Comment: Did you notice the above code, the white spaces are removed, and is posted not like ordinary message

Comment: There's a little orange question mark on the top right of the question text box. If you click that it will show you how to use the features of the text editor.

Comment: Moving this to meta, but hit the `edit` link to see what changes I made to format your code.

Comment: *I got tired to put the code in SO* really? Ever wanted to put code in a Wordpress blog? I am so glad SO uses Markdown....

Comment: I changed it from "post the code" to "post code" - let me know if you meant "post teh codez".

Answer (score 5):

you need to put a blank line between the text and the code

and indent the code with 4 spaces.

```
like this
```